# IONIC v1 IOS Controller refresh issues

Tags: ionic-framework

Hi… I’m still working with Ionicv1 in some proyects… I face a problem in IOS and i can;t find the problem maybe someone has allready face something similar and solve ir some way.

usually in on.’$ionicView.afterEnter’ I call the my REST service to get the data to update the view. In Android this work fine. but in IOS this feature is not working .

nevertheless , if in any way I force the update of the screen , sliding the menu, or calling $ionicLoading., the view update the information.

Eg.

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function () {

    RestServiceCall.getData( function( data ){
        $scope.data = data
      }
    });
}
```

if i have a list with ng-repeat=“item in data” in this case the list is not refreshed in IOS until i force the update.

if i do

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function () {
    **$ionicLoading.show()**
    RestServiceCall.getData( function( data ){
        **$ionicLoading.hide()**
        $scope.data = data
      }
    });
}
```

in this case it refresh but is annnoying having to dark the screen just for refreshment.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use 1. $timeout function like below.

```
 RestServiceCall.getData( function( data ) {
     $timeout(function() {
       $scope.data = data
     }, 100); 
      }
 });
```

2. use $scope.$apply() function.